# How to get UDID for purposes of provisioning?

Tags: ios, uuid, uniqueidentifier, udid

It sounds like this topic has been beaten to death; but when you set up a provisioning profile for deployment to test devices, an arbitrarily generated UUID will not suffice, you need the actual UDID to include in the provisioning profile.  Sure, you could give users a set of instructions to go through to get the ID, and e-mail it to you - but it is much more customer-friendly and avoiding stupid mistakes to get it yourself in code - previously via `uniqueIdentifier` method.

So other than creating an ad-hoc UUID, has anyone come up with a good replacement that would work in iOS6, or has Apple provided some method of doing this?  I haven't been able to find it in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is gather UUIDS for provisioning profile:

I use [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) to gather my testers UUIDs. All the user needs to do is sign up using their mobile device. Then I can see their UUID and update the provisioning profile. Once they have access to the build they will receive an email showing them where to download it.

Comment: Actually, what prompted me to ask this question, was that TestFlight code that obtains UDID came up with a warning in XCode that it is deprecated.  So once Apple removes it from the API, I don't think TestFlight will be able to gather it for me.  What then?